# How to correctly disable auto-hide in Unity 2d?

Tags: 11.04, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the launcher to always show in Unity 2d?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62941/how-do-i-set-the-launcher-to-always-show-in-unity-2d)

I'm using unity-2d in ubuntu 11.04 since 3d version is not working good in virtual machines (i use virtualbox from MacOS X). All works fine except auto-hide.

With windows and Mac OS i get user for taskbar to be permanently on the screen - so i have issued "gconf-editor" and changed auto-hide for unity from "2" to "0". This stops it from hiding, but now all windows that i start (firefox, explorer etc) completely ignores unity taskbar and alignes themself on the left side of screen as if taskbar is hidden :(.

Is it any way to fix it and make fullscreen / newly created windows to correctly align themselves on the right side of taskbar and not ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alan's answer doesn't work on Unity 2D because it doesn't use Compize.

If I got you right this might be the solution for your question:
In gconf-editor enable "use_strut" in Unity 2D's settings (desktop -> unity-2d -> launcher). In addition Mariano Chavero has made "A simple GUI for Unity-2D Settings": http://marianochavero.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/a-simple-gui-for-unity-2d-settings-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: Thanks, that completely solves a problem. The name "use strut" is very... surprising. What is "strut"? O_O

Comment: In this case it means something like "to move away from the left border of the screen" (see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strut)

Answer (score -2):

1. Install **CompizConfig Settings Manager**.

   `sudo apt-get install
   compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Navigate to the **Ubuntu Unity
   Plugin** tab.
3. Change **Hide Launcher** to
       **Never**, and go back.
4. Scroll down to the **Place Windows**
   tab.
5. Experiment with the **Placement
   Mode** until you find what you are
   looking for.

---

I don't have Unity, otherwise I would know what Placement Mode you need.