# How do I set the launcher to always show in Unity 2d?

Tags: launcher, 11.10, unity-2d

I have install ubuntu 11.10 and use unity-2d.
The Unity-2d auto hide.
I want it to be always show

Answer (score 8):

## For 11.10

The following terminal commands will set the launcher to always show:

First install the dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then input these lines to configure the launcher:

```
dconf write /com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher/hide-mode 0
dconf write /com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher/use-strut true
```

See also:

- [How do I configure Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d)

Comment: The GUI got updated: http://marianochavero.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/unity-2d-settings-ui-for-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Answer (score 2):

The GUI tool now works in 11.10 as well :)
http://marianochavero.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/unity-2d-settings-ui-for-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Answer (score 1):

## For 11.04

There's a GUI tool to do that.
[image]
[32-bit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3559201/2D-Desktop%20Settings%200.9/2d-desktop-settings_0.9.2-1_i386.deb)
[64-bit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3559201/2D-Desktop%20Settings%200.9/2d-desktop-settings_0.9.2-1_amd64.deb)

Comment: Do you have the link to this project or something so we can link to that instead of debs on dropbox?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is the blog post of the guy who made the application: http://marianochavero.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/a-simple-gui-for-unity-2d-settings-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: It doesn't work in ubuntu11.10

Comment: @lingyired Sorry, didn't know that. I only installed 11.10 today.