# How to correctly disable auto-hide in Unity 2d, Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the launcher to always show in Unity 2d?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62941/how-do-i-set-the-launcher-to-always-show-in-unity-2d)

Seems that my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38410/how-to-correctly-disable-auto-hide-in-unity-2d) is resurrected by the release of Ubuntu 11.10 :(. I have disabled Unity2D autohide via gconf-editor as answered - but it is still auto hiding! What i'm doing wrong?